# Как найти точку относительно от конечной точки с определенной длиной

Tags: c#, математика, геометрия

у меня возникла проблема при нахождении точки в пространстве OXY. У меня есть прямая с двумя  точками A и B, мне нужно достроить к этой прямой небольшой отрезок с определенной длиной (красная прямая). Для этого я нахожу направляющий вектор прямой **vect = B - A**, потом с помощью уравнения прямой с направляющий вектором ***(X-X0)/vect.X = (Y-Y0)/vect.Y***, хочу найти точку C . **Вопрос**: как мне задать длину отрезка для моего уравнения? Ниже приведен пример моего кода

```
private static Point3D CalcPoint(Vector3D vector3, Point3D point0, double length)
        {
            //Применяется уравнение прямой по направляющему вектору x/p1 = (y - y0) / p2 + x0 / p1
            //p - направляющий вектор, (x0; y0) - конечные точки прямой (в нашем случае начальные координаты)
            Point3D point = new Point3D();
            //Проверка вектора на параллельность к осям
            var signX = Math.Sign(vector3.X);
            var signY = Math.Sign(vector3.Y);
            if (vector3.X == 0)
            {
                point.X = point0.X;
                point.Y = point0.Y - (length * signY);
                return point;
            }
            if (vector3.Y == 0)
            {
                point.Y = point0.Y;
                point.X = point0.X - (length * signX);
                return point;
            }
            point.Y = point0.Y - (length * signY);
            point.X = ((point.Y - point0.Y) / vector3.Y + point0.X / vector3.X) * vector3.X;
            return point;
        }
```

[image: Прямая]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Направляющий вектор B-A, а не то, что указано. Нужно его нормализовать (привести к единичной длине) и прибавить к B

```
D = B - A
len = D.length() = sqrt(D.x * D.x + D.y * D.y) 
uD  =  D / len
//наверное, для Vector3D есть готовая функция нормализации
C = B + length * uD
```

Comment: vector3.Normalize();
vector3.Negate();
point = point0 + vector3 * length;
Вот так все правильно работает.

Comment: Я так и не понял, почему заработала когда инвертировал знаки в векторе.

Comment: Если C располагается так, как на рисунке, то инверсии не должно быть, но я не знаю, кто у Вас point0 и т.д.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое))